# Trouble creating admin account in Jenkins for Windows

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

Hello I just enabled Legacy mode authorization in Jenkins and it seems that it has now locked me out of all the administrative privileges.

I need to create an admin account so that I can continue with Jenkins configuration. I have direct access to the server and have tried running this line from command line:
`java -jar jenkins.war --argumentsRealm.passwd.jenkins=swordfish --argumentsRealm.roles.jenkins=admin` Jenkins starts but I am unable to access it from the web when starting from command line.

I've also tried starting Jenkins through services.msc, which is how I typically start it, and passing it the parameters `--argumentsRealm.passwd.jenkins=swordfish --argumentsRealm.roles.jenkins=admin`. Jenkins starts and I am able to access it through the web, but unable to log in with the username.

Any ideas how get admin access back?

Comment: I deleted the entries related to security and authentication in the config.xml and I am able to access again.

Comment: You might want to put your comment as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the entries related to security and authentication in the config.xml, restarted, and I am able to access again. I was able to add myself as an admin using matrix based security. Still not sure how to do it with legacy tho.

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/ says in the “Legacy mode” section “**Do not use this setting**…”; we may now know why.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had the same problem.  I would try to login to jenkins (hosted on glassfish), and would encounter the same thing. Basically getting a glassfish error that the application was not available.  If I cleared all temporary internet files from browser, browse to jenkins home page, I would be presented with the Jenkins login, and when I provided the correct userID and password, WHAMMO! Back to application not available....   This too was using matrix-based administration.

To fix:

1. Locate the config.xml of the userID that is experiencing problems, under "users" directory.
2. Deleted the "apiToken" tag under "jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty" tag.
3. Bounced glassfish and was able to login again.